# What windows functions would the BlockInput function break?

Tags: windows, input

Windows includes something called [BlockInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646290(v=vs.85).aspx) which basically disables user input. What(if any) functions would this function potentially break. Obviously this breaks  GetKeyState and GetKeyboardState. More specifically I am interested on if and how it affects:

- SendInput
- [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Blocking  of non-keyboard-mouse input (ex. controller)

Comment: The doc you've linked answers most of your questions: `GetKeyState` and `GetKeyboardState` are **not** affected; `SendInput` can only be affected by the **same** thread; controller events are not covered by this mechanism. The last question you have is hard to answer as you are asking about "programs" but giving an example of a script (lua)?

Comment: Lua is a script, Lua macros is a program similar to AHK and formally HID macros. My question in regards to those is how they would be interfered with or interfere with other programs. In regards to SendInput, does that mean that you can send input in that thread or that you can only send input in every other thread. Ans what about raw Input?

Comment: "How other programs are affected" really depends on **what are those programs doing**. There are several ways to manage events in Windows, some of those allow a program to inject events at a very low level. In general it is impossible to answer your question without knowing the internal details of those programs.

Comment: I realize now that that part is way too generic and is better for after my program is built. I have removed that from my question but I believe that the Raw Input part still has not been answered.